# How to compare string in JSP

Tags: string, if-statement, jsp

I'm trying to detect the name of the page `index.jsp` and compare it with the one I need.

```java
<% 
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    String pageName = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    if (pageName=="index.jsp"){out.println(pageName); }
    out.println(pageName);
%>
```

It outputs - `index.jsp`, but does not do it twice, neither without `out.println()` functuion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String pageName = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
if (pageName.equals("index.jsp")){out.println(pageName); }

comparing string values in jsp you have to use .equals("") method